# Global unhandledrejection listener in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, error-handling, promise

Is there any equivalent for

`window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (event) => {});`

in React Native?

I know I could wrap the fetch api to handle most of the unhandledrejection events in a single place but the global handler would help with any promise not only the one coming from the fetch api.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an easy issue.

The "unhandledrejection" event is not yet supported by all browsers (see [browser compatibility on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection)). And the default React Native's Promises implementation has another mechanism to catch unhandled rejections (see [here](https://github.com/then/promise)).

If you want the functionality anyway (I wanted it also myself!), you can use a JS Promise library that implements it. [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html#global-rejection-events) is a good example. But then you have to make sure every Promise in your app uses this implementation.

For example, in the index.js file of your React Native app:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

// We use the "Bluebird" lib for Promises, because it shows good perf
// and it implements the "unhandledrejection" event:
global.Promise = Promise;

// Global catch of unhandled Promise rejections:
global.onunhandledrejection = function onunhandledrejection(error) {  
  // Warning: when running in "remote debug" mode (JS environment is Chrome browser),
  // this handler is called a second time by Bluebird with a custom "dom-event".
  // We need to filter this case out:
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    logError(error);  // Your custom error logging/reporting code
  }
};
```

Comment: > But then you have to make sure every Promise in your app uses this implementation.

Hi Pierre, can you elaborate on how to ensure every Promise in the app should use this? Does this mean putting `import Promise from 'bluebird';global.Promise = Promise;` in each and every Javascript file?

Comment: Hi @ashishb, if you modify a property on the `global` object (here `global.Promise`), it means it will be available from all JS code (every file) of your app at runtime. That's why here we initialize this property in the index.js file, which is the entry point for the app code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to install another promise implementation, you can simply use the one that comes with RN.

```js
global.Promise = require('promise')

require('promise/lib/rejection-tracking').enable({
  allRejections: true,
  onUnhandled: (id, error) => {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: This is correct. Also look at this simple package/file that nicely wraps it up for you: https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-promise-rejection-utils