# How to find source of Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: react-native

While working on a large inherited codebase I stumbled upon this not so helpful warning:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
true

console.warn @ YellowBox.js:67
onUnhandled @ Promise.js:43
onUnhandled @ rejection-tracking.js:71
(anonymous) @ JSTimers.js:256
_callTimer @ JSTimers.js:152
callTimers @ JSTimers.js:405
__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:349
(anonymous) @ MessageQueue.js:106
__guard @ MessageQueue.js:297
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:105
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
```

Is possible to get the file and line number of the promise that causes this rejection, without going through the entire code and adding catch() everywhere?

Comment: This life cycle method should help you `componentDidCatch`

Comment: Are you using fetch or axis to get your data? With axios you could use the interceptors feature and add more logging there. You could also do that with fetch I think.

Comment: @needsleep the app uses fetch, but the issue goes for all unhandled promises

Comment: For me it turned out this was due to calling `finally()` without a parameter. Took me ages to figure out so I did a longer write-up on how I identified the original stack trace of the promise at the end of this [issue I filed](https://github.com/then/promise/issues/161#issuecomment-1657389959). Hopefully this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a third party promise library which keeps additional stack traces, like Bluebird, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129335/10236907

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in you root component.

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(info)
}
```

> Don't log you error instead send it to you database so that you can fix the issue with more information.

[Read more about componentDidCatch() life cycle method here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not trigger for promise rejections