# React Native find what caused Possible unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, react-native, error-handling, promise, es6-promise

I haven't been paying attention to the logbox errors in my React Native app for a while as I was in a rush, now I just noticed that I have a warning every time I open my app, here is what I get when I tap it:

[image]

While I know this originates from something thrown in an async function or a rejected promise, I have so many things running when app launches and I have no idea where this warning is coming from. My app seems to be working normally and I've checked all my explicit `throw`s and `reject`s from my code, added `debugger` statements to everywhere I called them, but no avail. As seen from the screenshot, the stack trace isn't useful at all either.

How can I find the cause of unhandled promise rejection in React Native?

Comment: @honor that `id` is node's internal thing, nothing to do with my code.

Comment: @honor it wouldn't make sense to share more if I don't share the whole project as they are literally everywhere. there are also many try/catches too. the question is not about where the error is in my code, it's more about how to find causes of promise rejections in RN.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this you'd rather use a library that can help you get a longer and more detailed stack trace to pin point the issue. Check out [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129335/916701) to find some examples. In my experience [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) works great with react native and can produce a more extensive and helpful stack trace.

```
// App.tsx 

import Promise from 'bluebird';

if (__DEV__) {
    // replace global promise with Bluebird
    global.Promise = Promise;
}
```